# Write script to create multiple users with pre-defined passwords

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, passwords

So I would like to make a script that create users from users.txt running

```
useradd -m -s /bin/false users_in_the_users.txt
```

and fill the password from passwords.txt twice (to confirm the passwords)

This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assign file descriptors to users and passwords files
exec 3< users.txt
exec 4< passwords.txt
exec 5< passwords.txt

# Read user and password
while read iuser <&3 && read ipasswd <&4 ; do
  # Just print this for debugging
  printf "\tCreating user: %s with password: %s\n" $iuser $ipasswd
  # Create the user with adduser (you can add whichever option you like)
  useradd -m -s /bin/false $iuser
  # Assign the password to the user, passwd must read it from stdin
  passwd $iuser
done
```

The problem is, it does not fill the passwords. And 1 more thing, I want the script to fill the passwords twice.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supply the password on stdin.  Replace:

```
passwd $iuser
```

with:

```
passwd "$iuser" <<<"$ipasswd
$ipasswd"
```

or, as suggested by mklement0:

```
passwd "$iuser" <<<"$ipasswd"$'\n'"$ipasswd"
```

The incantation `<<<` creates a *here-string*.  The string that follows the `<<<` is provided as standard in to the command which precedes the `<<<`.  In this case we provide the two copies of the password that the `passwd` command wants.

(The script reads these passwords from a plain text file. I will assume that your situation is some special case for which this is not as dangerous as it normally would be.)

Comment: Thank you. I tried and I get this error

Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: Sorry, passwords do not match
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged

Comment: @BabaMok: That suggests that you haven't entered the here-string correctly; perhaps try on a single line with `passwd "$iuser" <<<"$ipasswd"$'\n'"$ipasswd"`. Also, just to state what may be obvious to some: this must be run as root (with `sudo`).

Comment: @BabaMok When I run it I get: `Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated successfully`.  If you received the message "passwords do not match," it might be because a stray character, maybe a tab or space, was entered.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you. It works!

I changed from passwd $iuser to passwd "$iuser"<<<"$ipasswd"$'\n'"$ipasswd" and it works! Thank you again guys

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks.  I updated the answer with your suggestions.

Comment: @John1024: I appreciate it; I hope it's OK that I incorporated your answer into mine, but I wanted to show how to make do without the file-descriptor redirection commands.

Comment: @mklement0 Just fine.  And your answer got my +1.

Comment: @mklement0 I am sorry because I am new in this website. I have clicked the check mark. Thank you you again for helping :)

Comment: @BabaMok: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked for you. And: no worries about not accepting John's answer right away; we all were new to this site once.

Answer (score 2):

**[John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28919425/45375) is the correct one** - his warning about reading passwords from plain-text files bears repeating.

Let me show the solution in context, **without the file-descriptor acrobatics** (`exec 3<`, ...):

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: Be sure to run this script with `sudo`.

# Read user and password
while read iuser ipasswd; do

  # Just print this for debugging.
  printf "\tCreating user: %s with password: %s\n" $iuser $ipasswd

  # Create the user with adduser (you can add whichever option you like).
  useradd -m -s /bin/false $iuser

  # Assign the password to the user.
  # Password is passed via stdin, *twice* (for confirmation).
  passwd $iuser <<< "$ipasswd"$'\n'"$ipasswd"

done < <(paste users.txt passwords.txt)
```

- `paste users.txt passwords.txt` reads *corresponding lines* from the two files and puts them on a *single* line, separated with `\t`.
- The result is piped to stdin via a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`).
- This allows `read` to read from a single source.
- `$\n` is an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) that produces a (literal) newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #! /bin/bash

   for i in {1..100}
    do
      `sudo mkdir -p /root/Desktop/userm$i`
      `sudo useradd -m -d /root/Desktop/userm$i -s /bin/bash userm$i`
       echo "userm$i:userm$i" | chpasswd

   done
```

this will create 100 users.
 user name will be (userm1-userm100).
 home directory will be /root/Desktop/(userm1-user100) 
password will be (userm1-userm100)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this line:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/false $iuser
```

Try this one:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/false -p $ipasswd $iuser
```

You don't actually need this:

```
passwd $iuser <<< "$ipasswd"$'\n'"$ipasswd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#purpose: bash script to create multiple users with pre-defined passwords at once.
#Read_Me: The import file should be in two columns, first users name and second passwords.
#author: Bablish Jaiswal
#contact: linux.cnf@gmail.com

    read -p "Kindly import/type Users Name-password file with location:- " creation_info
    cat $creation_info |while read i p
    do
            ( useradd  $i   &&  echo -e "${p}\n${p}" |  passwd  $i )  > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo $user ${i} created and password is ${p} || echo ${i} failed 
    done
```